# Django post request doing nothing

Tags: python, django, web

So i'm not even sure how to search for someone who had the same thing happen to them.

I'm working on a django website and my form won't post to my database, instead, i get redirected to a URL containing the information that was in the forms, like this:

```
<form id="form">
      <input type="hidden" id="compinp" name="compinp">
      <input maxlength="20" onkeyup="showpost()" name="title" id="titleinput">
                    {{ captcha }}
</form>
```

Where compinp is some other data that gets posted, {{ captcha }} is a reCaptcha checkbox that works just fine, and when everything is filled in and getting posted, instead of running the post function from `views.py`, instead i get redirected to this:

> http://localhost:8000/newentry/?compinp=XXXX&title=XXXX&g-recaptcha-response="xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"

It gets posted via jQuery through a button outside of the form, though i tried to add a submit button inside it and got the exact same thing.

The `views.py` function that handles that looks like this:

```
def newentry(request):
    if request.method == "GET" and request.user.is_authenticated():
        #creating objects for the view, works fine too
        return render(request, "newentry.html",
                      {"champlist": complist, "captcha": captcha})
    elif request.method == "POST" and request.user.is_authenticated():
        captcha = Captcha(request.POST)
        title = request.POST.get("title", False)
        compname = request.POST.get("compinp", False)
        comp = Comp.objects.get(title=compname)
        if captcha.is_valid() and title and compname:
            newe= entry_generator(request.user, title, comp)
            newe.save()
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            return redirect('/')
    else:
         handle_home(request.method, request.user)
```

This view tries to post models from another app in the same project, if that makes it any different.

I had added a `print` attempt at the right after the request check for post it didn't print anything.

Not sure what other info i can give to help, if you want any, just ask (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the form method post:

```
<form id="form" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" id="compinp" name="compinp">
  <input maxlength="20" onkeyup="showpost()" name="title" id="titleinput">
                {{ captcha }}
</form>
```

Comment: You're welcome. it it works, please accept the answer, it will be heplful